# Write a scroll callback that gets called at regular intervals

Tags: javascript, events, scroll

I want to write a scroll callback function that gets called after every one second when user scrolls. I tried

```
window.on('scroll', function(e) {
//scroll function body
});
```

But the problem is it gets called everytime user scrolls even one pixel. Can someone please suggest a solution.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like this

```
scrollCb = function(func, later) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

and call it like

```
scrollCb(function() {
   //Your scroll callback handler 
}, 1000);
```